# How to programmatically get the theme main color in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Is there a way that I can grab the active theme main color like `get_user_option( 'admin_color' )`. Otherwise what is the best way? I know theme options are stored under wp_options under like `theme_mods_twentyfifteen` but is there an easier way to grab it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `get_theme_mod()` function would be the most appropriate for what you wanted. This relies on the theme actually saving a `main color` option of some kind as a theme_mod (they should be, really all theme modifications should be `theme_mod`s and not regular options).